# webstorm license in virtualbox, ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: linux, virtualbox, webstorm

I have installed webstorm 9 on Oracle VirtualBox and get the follwing error:

```
-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/WebStorm-139.252/bin$ ./webstorm.sh 
[    317]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - No valid license found 
java.lang.Throwable
    at

     com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:115)
        at com.intellij.ide.a.g.bb.a(bb.java:107)
        at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.start(MainImpl.java:47)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:105)
        at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:42)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:91)
        at java.lang.Thread.r

un(Thread.java:745)
[    318]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - WebStorm 9.0.1  Build #WS-139.252 
[    319]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - JDK: 1.7.0_65 
[    319]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
[    320]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[    320]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - OS: Linux
```

Linux/Java versions:

```
xxx@xxx-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/WebStorm-139.252/bin$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

- I have tried this with WebStorm 8 and got the same problem.
- I have tried this with the same on VMWare, here I had no problems.

Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exception usually means that no license information has been found in ~/.WebStorm9 folder and no GUI environment exists so that WebStorm can't open the License dialog to let you set the licensing options... Do you work on your Linux workstation directly, or access it remotely? Also please check if your OpenJDK has the graphical libraries included. Actually I'd suggest trying Oracle JDK instead

Comment: Thanks, Iena, for your answer. Probably the GUI environment is the reason. I'll check that and let you know. I access my Linux on my Workstation directly; Generally the graphical support is available, e.g. Mozilla etc. starts.

Comment: Solved this on Fedora 21 by installing the package `java-1.8.0-openjdk`. Fedora comes preinstalled with `java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless`, since LibreOffice depends on it, however, that's not enough to run Jetbrains' programs.